# Orbeon Forms Availability of feature in CE version

Tags: orbeon

Wanted to understand the availability of patch in CE version. I am specifically looking at  "Upgrade Apache Commons Collections (#2929) patch to be applied on my production. [Orbeon Blog](http://blog.orbeon.com/)

Is is already part of CE version? What is the general strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbeon Forms PE releases occur more often than Orbeon Forms CE releases. This change for sure will be in the next major release of Orbeon Forms CE and PE (which is meant to be version 2016.3).

Now this particular change happens to be very simple since you can simply update one JAR file, as shown in the [commit on GitHub](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/commit/c3b68829b821f9c948c0d067569ff63dcacb6586). If you do the patch yourself you won't even need a formal release.